# I want to add a command parameter to a Windows 7 startup item

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, boot

How can I do this? MSConfig won't allow you to edit the command being sent, just enable or disable.

Comment: Modify its shortcut in the Startup folder or its entry in the registry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit these entries in the registry.  I personally can never remember where the run commands are stored, so I use [Startup Control Panel](http://web.archive.org/web/20120921223440/http://mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml).  You can get it as either a Control Panel snap-in or as a standalone exe.  Either way, it will show you all of the items that are running on startup (startup folder for you, for the system, and all the registry locations).  You can then click the one you want, select edit, and add a command-line parameter after it.

[image: Startup Control Panel]

Comment: I really used to like SCP a lot. It was my pick for this task for a long time. Unfortunately there were a few little things that bugged me about it, but there was no response to bug-reports or feature requests and in fact, rumors started spreading that Mike Lin **had died**. `:-o` To this day, I don’t know if they’re true or not.

Comment: I just remembered one of my gripes with SCP: it does not support environment variables, only flat strings.

Comment: @Synetech He died?!  That's quite the rumor... though I see his domain name is registered through 2014, so could be and we won't find out until it lapses.

Comment: @Craig Glad you like it!  I've used it for years.  Please accept it as the answer if this is your best option.  You may want to wait a few days in case someone has something better to say though. :)

Comment: The rumors were circulating on the discussion/support group, but it has long since died out and been flooded with spam. His [about](http://www.mlin.net/about.shtml) page has not been updated in years. Googling for ["mike lin" programmer dead](https://www.google.com/search?q="mike+lin"+programmer+dead) brings up a most interesting mix of results, especially at this date.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a start up item in the startup folder, right click the shortcut and click properties. Under target, add your parameters after the quotation marks

Comment: Thanks guys. These items aren't in the Startup folder though.